# JavaScript: How to toggle HTML5 video fullscreen / non-fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-fullscreen

Given is an `HTML5` video element. A button should change this video element into fullscreen, or end the fullscreen.

I have already written a `JavaScript` function. This works fine in `Firefox`. Unfortunately, the function does not work in Google Chrome.

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
    var player = document.querySelector('#playerContainer');
    if (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitFullScreen) {
        if (player.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            player.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } 
        else {
            player.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        }
    } else {
        if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        }
    }
}
```

While everything works fine in `Firefox`, in `Chrome`, the window is positioned only in the middle of the full-screen window. Also, Chrome can not quit the fullscreen.

I used `Firefox Quantum 61.0.1` and `Google Chrome 68.0`.

Answer (score 1):

I see a note in devdocs, maybe useful for you:

It's worth noting a key difference here between the Gecko and WebKit implementations at this time: Gecko automatically adds CSS rules to the element to stretch it to fill the screen: 
`width: 100%; height: 100%`

WebKit doesn't do this. 
Instead, it centers the fullscreen element at the same size in a screen that's otherwise black. To get the same fullscreen behavior in WebKit, you need to add your own "`width: 100%; height: 100%;`" CSS rules to the element yourself:

```
#myvideo:-webkit-full-screen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That's a very good hint! Thank you, I did not think that. However, Chrome does not close the fullscreen. For some reason player.webkitRequestFullScreen() is also called when I try to close fullscreen. It only works with the Esc key.

Comment: Try to use this method:player.webkitExitFullScreen

Comment: It's a problem with the first IF statement. Chrome also calls the request function in fullscreen. The exit function is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem... it failed because I used the wrong function in the first if-statement:

Wrong:

```
if (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitFullScreen) { ... }
```

Correct:

```
if (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen) { ... }
```